# Play 2.2.1 plugin not loaded

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am writing a plugin which builds up an index on a Solr server extending the `BeanPersistAdapter` class. I actually moved the code to become a plugin and since then it doesn't work anymore. I did not make any changes to it.

My plugin is located in app/com.myplugin but there's no class extending `play.Plugin` as my the main functionality is implemented in the class which already extends `BeanPersistAdapter` for `isRegisterFor(Class<?> clazz)`, `postInsert(BeanPersistRequest<?> request)`, ... methods.
I make the plugin known to my Application in the conf/play.plugins file with `5000:com.myplugin`

**Edit:** It needs to be `5000:com.myplugin.Plugin` (i.e. the class which extends play.Plugin needs to be specified)

Could anyone tell what's to be done so that I won't get this Exception

```
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load plugin[Plugin [com.myplugin]
cannot been instantiated.]
        at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply
(Application.scala:159) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply
(Application.scala:128) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-libra
ry.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
 ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myplugin
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0
_40]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your class looks like:

```
public class myplugin extends BeanPersistAdapter {
.....
}
```

Under the hood playframework loads Plugins like that:

```
val plugin = classloader.loadClass(className).getConstructor(classOf[play.Application]).newInstance(new play.Application(this)).asInstanceOf[Plugin]
```

Thus your `myplugin` is not instance of `Plugin`. You need to implement interface `play.api.Plugin`:

```
public class myplugin extends BeanPersistAdapter implements play.api.Plugin {

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the documentation I read that play.Plugin should be extended, so I didn't think of the interface. There's actually a new problem coming up now with the BeanPersistAdapter. Maybe you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371960/use-of-beanpersistadapter-in-a-plugin

Comment: I'd love to help but I don't know what are you talking about :)

Comment: Well, this is some Ebean related stuff. Is it not clear or do you just don't know the problem/solution?

Comment: For db access layer I use jOOq in play. I used anorm, but never ebean :)

Comment: I have to deal with an existing system and add some magic to it. No choice, it's my thesis. But thanks for pointing out jOOq and anorm, will have a look at them!